# Mounting docker socket into container crashes rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, docker, docker-compose

We have a small inhouse app that I have to maintain. This app starts new docker containers and runs on an old ruby(2.2)/rails(4.2) version.
Since it is not possible to install this ruby version on new Ubuntu's - wrong version of libssl in the repositories and I have not found a way to install an old version and a new version in parallel - I decided that I put this app inside a docker container.

This works except, when I try to mount the docker socket into it the rails server crashes on startup - the app want's to access the socket during this time to display all running containers.
I already made sure that the docker group is the same for the host and the container with this:

```
ARG DOCKER_GROUP_ID
USER root

RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list  
RUN echo "deb http://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

RUN groupadd -g $DOCKER_GROUP_ID docker && usermod -a -G docker root
```

And during build time I pass this argument:

> docker-compose build --build-arg DOCKER_GROUP_ID=`getent group docker | cut -d: -f3`

When I connect to the container and call `docker info` I get a result and the container is still ok...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you specified `ARG DOCKER_GROUP_ID` somewhere in your Dockerfile? Otherwise, the `--build-arg` flag doesn't have any effect. Also, is there any error message coming from your rails container?

Comment: I have the ARG flag in my Dockerfile. I edited my post to show where it is

Comment: Ok, but you still owe us an error message. :) Or why do you think the rails server crashed? What is happening exactly and what do you want to happen?

Comment: The problem is, that I just can't see an error message... . When I start the container with running rails it shuts down immidiatly after it booted. When I start the bash instead of puma, I can access docker and everything seems to be ok. Maybe you know a way how to access an error log?